# mongoTemplate query for composite key

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

Lets say I have a mongo collection as follows:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "index" : "index1",
        "version" : 1
        }
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "index" : "index2",
        "version" : 2
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "index" : "index1",
        "version" : 3
    }
}
```

I would like to write a query using Spring's mongoTemplate to retrieve only those documents with _id.index = index1.

Using mongo shell I can write this query as follows:

```
db.collectionName.find({"_id.index" : "index1"})
```

However what I assumed would work using mongoTemplate does not.  I have tried:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id.index").is("index1"));
mongoTemplate.find(query, SomeJavaObject.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax for this query using mongoTemplate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, this is not really a valid question.  The mongoTemplate query I quote in the question does work.  I was calling it with the wrong _id.index, oops :)

I can't seem to delete the question but maybe it will help someone doing a composite key query...